# WhatsApp media types support?

Tags: twilio, whatsapp

I see WhatsApp supports other response types such as:

- Lists
- Multi-product message
- Product display page (PDP)
- Cart
- Order message

Are these accessible via the Twilio platform? We currently integrate via Twilio conversations and wondered if these are supported? I could not find anything when I searched the documentation.

Comment: Yes, Twilio Conversations supports all of these response types. You can find more information in the Twilio Conversations documentation.

Comment: I can't see anything specific to the WhatsApp formats above in the Twilio documentation:  

https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations

The documentation only seems to cover text and media types.